# only one color is displayed in time

Tags: java, android, colors, custom-view

I'm developing paint app the problem is when i choose color and paint and then pick different color the whole paint color changes to the new color can any one tell why this is happening and how to solve this ?  and how to add eraser to this?
imageview DrawView here :

```
public class DrawView extends ImageView {
    private ArrayList<Point> mTouches;
    int paintColor;
    public int setcolor(int a){
        paintColor=a;
        return paintColor;}
    // Java constructor
    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();}
    // XML constructor
    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();}
    private void init() {
        mTouches = new ArrayList<Point>();}
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Capture a reference to each touch for drawing
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        mTouches.add(new Point(Math.round(touchX), Math.round(touchY)));
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);}
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        // Let the image be drawn first
        super.onDraw(c);
        // Draw your custom points here
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(paintColor);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        for (Point p : mTouches) {
            c.drawCircle( p.x, p.y,15,paint);}} }
```

in my main:

```
im.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                DrawView mcustomImagview = (DrawView) v;
                mcustomImagview.setcolor(color);
                mcustomImagview.invalidate();
                if (v.onTouchEvent(event)) {
// Do something with event.getX(), event.getY() }
                return true;}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `onDraw` is called, the entire canvas is redraw. As you store only one paintColor in your custom class, only the last selected one is used.

You need to store the color together with the associated Point. Then when you loop throw your `mTouches` array, you change the color for the color of the current Point.

Btw the `Paint` object can be updated, so you don't need to create it every time as it's a bad practice to create new objects in `onDraw`.

### EDIT

```
public class DrawView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    private ArrayList<ColouredPoint> mTouches;
    // Current used colour
    private int mCurrColour;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public void setColor(int colour) {
        mCurrColour = colour;
    }

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    // XML constructor
    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTouches = new ArrayList<>();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(mCurrColour);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Capture a reference to each touch for drawing
        float touchX = event.getX();
        float touchY = event.getY();
        mTouches.add(new ColouredPoint(Math.round(touchX), Math.round(touchY), mCurrColour));

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        // Let the image be drawn first
        super.onDraw(c);
        // Draw your custom points here
        for (ColouredPoint p : mTouches) {
            mPaint.setColor(p.colour);
            c.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 15, mPaint);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Class to store the coordinate and the colour of the point.
     */
    private class ColouredPoint {
        int x;
        int y;
        int colour;

        public ColouredPoint(int x, int y, int colour) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.colour = colour;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean i have t create paint and set color out site ondraw method ? @Eselfar

Comment: You can initialise your Paint when you create the view (in your `init` method). then you can do `mPaint.setColor()` in `onDraw` to set the color you want to use.
Basically instantiate new objects is time consuming and `onDraw` needs to have an execution time as short as possible.

Comment: still doing the same the old points color change to the new color !!

Comment: Yes of course. This part was just to improve your code.
But as I said above, you have to store ALL the colours and not only the last one. If I understand correctly your user chooses a colour, draws, chooses another colour, draws, and so on. So each time the user draws something you need to store the colour somewhere to be able to redraw it later.

Comment: I've edited my answer above with an example. Could be improved but it should work.

Comment: thank you very much it's working now , i have another question how can i set the view in the center of layout i'm adding android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center" and still not on the center !

Comment: I don't know, I need to see your code. But it's better to ask another question for that. Don't forget to include your layout. Do a bit of search first as there is already a lot of people with similar issues.

Comment: Can you answer this question please ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524940/coloring-imageview-old-touches  it's the same but for drawing paths @Eselfar

Comment: If the question is the same, the answer is the same. You need to store the colour of the point, for every points! At the moment you store only one colour and you replace it every time the user selects a new one, that why everything change to the last selected colour. Your new question is basically a duplicate question of this one. It's pointless for me to answer the new question as it means you haven't understood my answer above.

Comment: they are paths now this is the problem i don't know how to create a class for paths , anyway thank you @Eselfar

Comment: You need your custom class to `extends` the class `Path`. Then you can add your colour field. We could have done the same for the case above but was pointless as the `Point` class contains only `x` and `y`.

Comment: can you tell how to erase ontouch also

Comment: To erase ontouch? What do you mean? To let the user erase an existing path by touching it?

Comment: Hum... I'm not quite sure. One method is to find which point/path is drawn at the coordinates of the touch event and then remove it from your array. But it's tricky as you need to take the size of the point in consideration in your calculation, and 2 points can overlap so in that case you need to remove only the one on top. Maybe there is an easier solution or a lib which does that. I'd recommend you to ask a new question. If you do so, please share the link in a comment below as I'm interested in the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592270/app-crash-after-using-eraser this question