# app crash when deleting item from array list

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, paint, eraser

my app crash when i try to remove object from array list :

```
for (ColouredPaths p : mTouches) {
            if(erase){
                if(p!=null)
                {  mTouches.remove(p);}

            }
```

why this is happening and how o fix ?

Comment: @K. Sopheak  This is not beta user build this is it

Comment: @K.Sopheak This is not beta user build this is it

Comment: No, this is a Java `Collections` behavior. I explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a `ConcurrentException`, it means you're looping through a list that you're modifying. In ArrayLists, you can't do this. Try using a `Queue` like this, instead of an `ArrayList`:

```
Queue<ColouredPaths> mTouches = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

You can loop through it the same way, but it shouldn't crash anymore.

Comment: @rgl Did this fix it? I've used `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`s for a while, and they seem to work well.

Comment: can you help me adding eraser to this view !! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415757/only-one-color-is-displayed-in-time Cause I can't delete the touched point I can only delete the whole paint , thank in advance